Как из WSL подключиться к OpenServer
Есть приложение на Flask - он подключается к БД. На локальной машине если запускать на Windows, то все прекрасно подключается, а если это же приложение запустить через WSL, то он не видит БД, которая на OpenServer запущена.
Какие конфиги надо поковырять, чтобы из WSL подключиться к БД?

а вообще ваш WSL интернет видит? попробуйте пинг гугл

@ESkri да - пингует.
